# Can the Stack Exchange websites work with a small cookie notification?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, notifications, cookies

The massive cookie acceptance notification is a major annoyance. Even more annoying, is that even if I've logged into Stack Overflow, when I visit another Stack Exchange website, I'm shown the annoying notification again and I don't even get automatically logged in. Incognito tabs.

[image]

Earlier when it was a thin notification at the bottom of the page which could be dismissed by one click, it wasn't all that annoying. But now it's thrown in our face and we have to click twice if we don't want cookies tracking us.

Please make that notification smaller. By default, nobody wants cookies tracking them. That's a given. If someone is ok with the tracking, you can give them one button that says "I consent".

Comment: I'm not sure but I can imagine some clever lawmaker put a *the cookie consent popup shouldn't be obscured or easily missed, fine is 10,000 Euro for not compliant occurances* in the actual text that lead to this thing.

Comment: @rene Nope, that did not happen. [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj) says websites should assume no-consent by default, so if the users don't see a consent banner they simply don't abdicate any right. The reason of the huge banner is exactly to annoy users and induce them to dismiss it as soon as possible, and we know what the shortest path is.

Comment: @Quasímodo meh, that is the unfavorable explanation. :(

Comment: @rene Yeah, and I would like to believe otherwise, but the silence of the team responsible for this banner seems to just confirm it.

Comment: @Quasímodo in their defense: they need the ad revenue to cover some of the dev budget for the free public QA offering.

Comment: @rene Certainly, and I am not saying making money is evil, but I think the method employed here is very questionable. I think the previous footer banner was noticeable, and if a user wanted to be tracked, he would fairly choose so. With such a large banner I'd say users are *compelled* to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen many sites showing the "accept cookies" banners. This one on SE is by far the most big, intrusive, and annoying of them all.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard I've seen them far more big and intrusive then this tiny banner. I know of sites that just completely fill your screen until you make a choice.

Comment: @Luuklag luckily didn't stumble on such sites. Not that the sites I visit are better than SE, they do have ads on 80% of the page, just not the cookie banner.

Comment: This one, and the one I just linked as a duplicate are very related, so for book-keeping purposes I'm closing this one as a duplicate of the older one. If you do feel you have anything to add to the duplicate target, feel free to write answers or comments there :)

Comment: This is part of a bug around cookies that is currently being investigated by the team.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. It is answered on the question linked at the top.